# Changing CRS of GeoJSON

Tags: coordinate-system, geojson, geopandas

I'm trying to change the CRS of a dataset loaded from GeoJSON.

input:

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" } },
"features": [
    { "type": "Feature", "properties": { }, "geometry": { "type": "LineString", "coordinates": [ [ 0.1038536, 52.1597749 ], [ 0.1036437, 52.15966 ], [ 0.1035028, 52.1596008 ], [ 0.1034112, 52.15958 ], [ 0.1033066, 52.1595636 ], [ 0.1031661, 52.1595526 ] ] } }
]
}
```

Code:

```py
import geopandas

dataset = geopandas.read_file("test_input.geojson")
dataset["geometry"] = dataset['geometry'].to_crs(epsg=27700)
dataset.to_file("test_output.geojson", driver="GeoJSON")
```

Output:

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" } },
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { }, "geometry": { "type": "LineString", "coordinates": [ [ 544009.098911162582226, 253364.318673640082125 ], [ 543995.113103618961759, 253351.124147661554161 ], [ 543985.666951830964535, 253344.260967869311571 ], [ 543979.468891219468787, 253341.766085840528831 ], [ 543972.367475303239189, 253339.734753260971047 ], [ 543962.793192178476602, 253338.232765670283698 ] ] } }
]
}
```

There are two problems:

- The CRS in the output is not correct
- The coordinates are completely off

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What if you use `to_crs("EPSG:27700")`? What gives you as output of `print(dataset["geometry"])`? By the way did you set up the initial crs?

Comment: `to_crs("EPSG:27700")` yields the same result. Print dataset gives me this output: `0    LINESTRING (544009.099 253364.319, 543995.113 ...`

Comment: What if you take a copy of your layer and try `dataset_proj = dataset.copy() dataset_proj['geometry'] = dataset_proj['geometry'].to_crs({'init': 'epsg:27700'})`?

Comment: Still the same result, but now the geojson doesn't include the CRS at all

Comment: Even with a copy?

Comment: Yes, copied your exact code, same result

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105685/discussion-between-kenneth-and-taras).

Comment: I believe that the coordinates are not off, see https://epsg.io/map#srs=27700&x=544009.098911163&y=253364.31867364&z=7&layer=streets